# Extra typename keyword in template parameter list: is it valid or not?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, typename

The following code compiles successfully with *clang 3.5.0* and *g++ 4.9.0* (with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` flags) under [C++03 (flag `-std=C++03`)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed5542c3bacbc936), [C++11 (flag `-std=C++11`)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5906c44aadfaa3a3), and [C++14 (flag `-std=C++14`)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7aeaac50c6c04736):

```
namespace N
{
    typedef int T;

    enum E{};
}

template <typename N::T>
struct ST{};

template <typename N::E>
struct SE{};

int main()
{
}
```

**Is it valid to add extra `typename` keyword before a non-type template parameter declaration?**

---

Note that the following code doesn't compile (as [C++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0092df757c74ca72), [C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2a95005e85182c1), and [C++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a49f96cc87377e55) code):

```
typedef int T;

enum E{};

template <typename T t>
struct ST{};

template <typename E e>
struct SE{};

int main()
{
}
```

But the following one compiles fine again ([C++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08f4b661cd7379cb), [C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb166fe85447926a), and [C++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/069a32bb1ca79559)):

```
typedef int T;

enum E{};

template <typename ::T>
struct ST{};

template <typename ::E>
struct SE{};

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `typename N::T` gets parsed as a type parameter, unrelated to the actual type `N::T`. The name of that is strange, however.

Comment: @dyp And what should follow from your quote?

Comment: @leemes Yes, I think so, too. And it is *very* strange.

Comment: @Constructor Oops, sorry, I was confused. I read *the nested-name-specifier* instead of *the qualified-id*.

Comment: @dyp Nothing wrong. :)

Comment: Ok, it looks like my assumption is wrong. It's not a type parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is allowed, but only with qualified names:

> *typename-specifier:*
>           `typename` *nested-name-specifier identifier*
>            `typename` *nested-name-specifier*
>   `template`*<sub>opt</sub> simple-template-id*

So `typename E` is wrong according to the grammar. `typename N::E` is not since the name is qualified. The third case, `typename ::E`, is fine since `::` is a valid nested-name-specifier.

The C++03 standard specifies in [temp.res]/5 that

> The keyword `typename` shall be applied only to qualified names, but
>   those names need not be dependent.

The C++11 standard states this nowhere explicitly but inside a note in [temp.names]/5:

> [ *Note:* As is the case with the `typename` prefix, the `template`
>   prefix is allowed in cases where it is not strictly necessary; i.e.,
>   when the *nested-name-specifier* or the expression on the left of the
>   `->` or `.` is not dependent on a *template-parameter*, or the use
>   does not appear in the scope of a template. *— end note* ]

The same note exists in the exact same place in the C++14 standard.

Comment: So if the name is not dependent then `typename` is superfluous?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes. `typename` is for disambiguation; if there's no need for disambiguation, then `typename` is not required ;)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Certainly.

Comment: @dyp : Not required, but, is it permitted (and e.g. silently ignored)?

Comment: @ildjarn Yes, see the note quoted in the answer, and [CWG DR 382](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#382)